# How to return the last index of a group in a list Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list in following form:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0]
```

each of the items in the list is a small decimal number. I'm looking for a way of returning the last index position of each group. In the above example it would be something like:

```
0: 3, 1: 6, 0.6: 8, 0: 11
```

I'm fairly new to python and I don't really know how to approach this

Comment: I'd like to point out that printing the first index will give you `0` and one more than each last index you are looking for (except for last index in list) so a solution to find the first index could be adapted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
a=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0]
i=0
while(i<=len(a)):
    if (i == len(a)-1):
        print(str(a[i]) + ":" + str(i))
        break
    if(a[i]!=a[i+1]):
       print(str(a[i])+":"+str(i))
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Wonderful! I had thought in this direction but couldn't figure out how to implement it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) may be useful here, it deals with pretty much everything except tracking the indices which isn't hard to do yourself:

```
import itertools

a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0]
i = 0
for val, group in itertools.groupby(a):
    for inst in group:
        # each element that is the same in sequence, increment index
        i += 1
    # after the inner for loop i will be the index of the first element of next group
    # so i - 1 is the index of last occurence.
    print(val, i - 1)
```

If you are particularly clever with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [variable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#abstract) you can make this super short although less obvious how it's working.

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0]
# still group only by value but now use enumerate to have it keep track of indices
for val, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(a), itemgetter(1)):
    # this is tuple unpacking, irrelevant is a list of values that aren't the last one, and last is the one we care about.
    [*irrelevent, last] = group
    print(last)
```

This answer is less intended to say "here's how you should do it" and more "this is some of the things that exist in python", happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll pick over these and hopefully learn something from them